# Puppet resource dependency

Tags: linux, puppet, infrastructure

**Hello everybody,**

When I do puppet apply, I get the error:

```
Warning: Scope(Mod::Cl[title]): Can't load '/tmp/file.yaml' File does not exist!
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value.
```

I specify that loadyaml is a function of stdlib module

However, i want to execute file resource before define resource

Someone can help me ?

```
class mod::princ (

    file { '/tmp/file.yaml':
        ensure  => file,
        owner   => 'root',
        group   => 'root',
        mode    => '0644',
        source  => "puppet:///modules/othermod/file.yaml",
        before => Mod::Cl["title"],
    }->
    Mod::Cl{ "title" :
        tmp_file => "/tmp/file.yaml",
    }

}

define mod::cl (
    String $tmp_file,
){

    $tmp = loadyaml("$tmp_file")

    $tmp[var].each |Integer $i, Hash[String,String] $var|
    {
      $mark=$var['Mark']
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using a Puppet master?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, with an apply or a Puppet master, I get the same error

Comment: Puppet first compiles the manifest and then applies it, but `loadyaml` (and other functions) run at compile time, while resources like `file` run at apply time. Read the file directly from the module (`othermod/file.yaml`), else explain what you're trying to achieve so we can help better - `mod::cl` doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Hello Dominic, thanks for the answer.
In fact, I read the file yaml and rewrite another one from the define mod::cl. 
I already tried to read the file directly from the module (othermod/file.yaml), but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As Dominic mentioned in his comment, the `loadyaml` function is run at compile-time.

If you are running Puppet via a Puppet Master/Server and `puppet agent`, this happens on the server, before the manifest is sent to the client, *not* on the client itself.

In addition, the `loadyaml` function is run at *compile*, not *execution* - so the file needs to exist *before* the Puppet run takes place.

I'd query why you're taking this approach with your Puppet code - you don't really explain what the code is for, or what your intended end-state looks like.

You can get the same results using Hiera.

**hieradata/common.yaml**

```
---
mod::princ::data:
  entry:
    foo: bar
  yrtne:
    oof: rab
```

**modules/mod/manifests/princ.pp**

```
class mod::princ (
  Hash $data
) {

  $data.each |Integer $i, Hash $elem, $var | {
    $mark=$var['Mark']
  }

}
```